# importing function from module python 3

Tags: python, function, module

I created the function

```
 def distance(x0, y0, x1, y1):
       import math
       return math.sqrt((x1 - x0)**2 + (y1 - y0)**2)
```

and saved it as distance.py
I then tried to run the code

```
from distance import distance
x0=input("Please input x0")
y0=input("Please input y0")
x1=input("Please input x1")
y1=input("Please input y1")
print ("")
print (distance())
```

using `x0 =10, y0=20, x1=50 y1=50` the answer should be `50.0`, but I get "function distance at 0x058625D0"

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch your code to:

```
from distance import distance
x0=float(input("Please input x0: "))
y0=float(input("Please input y0: "))
x1=float(input("Please input x1: "))
y1=float(input("Please input y1: "))
print ("")
print (distance(x0, y0, x1, y1))
```

You need to first convert the input values into floats so they work in your function, and then you need to actually pass them to your function.